# Не могу прикрепить Text к скрипту Unity

Tags: unity3d

Недавно начал изучать Unity и никак не могу разобраться со своей проблемой
[image: Вот структура если это важно]

Проблема заключается в том что я не могу присоединить Text который находится вне Button

[[image: 2]

Не выходит не поиском, не перетаскиванием

Выдаёт ошибку NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашло меня само, в скрипте я использовал просто Text вместо TMP